# Screen goes black when virtual keyboard hides - Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 / Android 3.1 / PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, screen, hide

If I position a text input in the lower half of a page, when the user taps it to show the virtual keyboard, the page automatically slides up. When you tap away from the keyboard, the page automatically slides down again. I.e., everything is fine.

But when the text input is located in the *top* half of the page (in which case the page doesn't automatically slide when the keyboard appears), the behaviour is bad:

1. User taps the text input;
2. The whole screen (except the text input) turns black momentarily, then the keyboard slides up;
3. The user taps away from the keyboard;
4. The screen flashes black before the page is rendered again.

However, if you try the above steps a *second* time, the sequence is:
1. Same as above;

1. Same as above;
2. Same as above;
3. The screen turns black and stays black;
4. The user taps on the black screen;
5. The page is shown again.

I've tried a few different things, like detecting when the text input loses focus (i.e., keyboard hidden) to show to page, scroll the page, etc. but nothing seems to prevent this problem with the black screen.

Showing a javascript alert when the text input loses focus avoids the black screen problem (but I don't want an alert to show either!).

I've also tried using android:hardwareAccelerated="true" inside my AndroidManifest.xml's  tag. And whilst that does fix this particular problem, it unfortunately creates many more rendering problems throughout the web app.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: In this activity, can you try some variations of `android:windowSoftInputMode`. For example, try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`

Comment: Many thanks for this. Using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" seems to have fixed the problem. The only problem is that the keyboard can make the next screen to be shown be scrolled up. However, I can fix this with window.scrollTo(0, 0); - so we're looking good!

Comment: @ban-geoengineering how to use this window.scrollTo(0, 0);

Comment: I'm not sure as I no longer use PhoneGap and I don't have access to the code now. But it is Javascript code, and I imagine it would have gone in some kind of init or onCreate method. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your manifest file in your launching activity tag

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Comment: Does anybody have an idea if this issue can be solved inside a service which uses the windowmanager to add views to the screen?